# PHP post method only showing the first word?

Tags: php, post

Can someone see where I have gone wrong? I have

```
                echo'<option value='.$row['car'].'>'.$row['car'].'</option>';               
            }
?>          
            </select>
```

I want to display the whole word in `$row['car']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You MUST have quotes around your attributes if they contain more than one word.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['car'].'">' . $row['car'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Better yet, just to always have them.