# Form <select> statement not parsing full values?

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post, form-submit

I have a working form code form.php as follows:

```
<?php
//database connection file setting.inc will need to be modified for production
include ("settings.inc");  

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
} 
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT `AllianceName`
    FROM `City` ORDER BY `AllianceName`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
?>
<html>
<form id='Alliance' name='' method='post' action='results.php'>
<p><label>Alliance Name:</label></p>
<select  style="width:300px" class="" id="AllianceName" size="1" name="Alliance">
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo '<option value='.$row['AllianceName'].'>'.$row['AllianceName'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<?php
$sql2 = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT `Continent`
    FROM `City` ORDER BY `Continent`
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql2)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
?>
<p><label>Continent:</label></p>
<select  style="width:300px" class="" id="Continent" size="1" name="Continent">
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo '<option value='.$row['Continent'].'>'.$row['Continent'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</html>
```

This calls results.php

```
<?php 
include ("settings.inc");  

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if(isset($_POST['Alliance']) )
{
  $varname = $_POST['Alliance'];
  $varcontinent = $_POST['Continent'];
}
echo $_POST['Alliance'];

$sql3 = <<<SQL
    SELECT * FROM `City` WHERE `AllianceName` = '$varname' 
    AND `Continent` = '$varcontinent'
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql3)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
?>
<html>
<?php
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       //arguments etc go here for displaying data in a table
   }
?>
```

Now, I am  certain that the results.php is fine, because I have tested with a static query coded in and it outputs data from the db.

My issue is peculiar, and I haven't found any documentation that explains why this would be happening.

In form.php, the alliance value selected can be a string of two or three words.  Now this string should just parse but what I am seeing is that it cuts off at the first space, ie if the string was "Have A Nice Day", my $_POST['alliance'] would only show the word "Have".

I have tried to add a length="255" attribute to the select tag for alliance, but that does not help.

Comment: Quote the value attribute in your `<option>` tag. as in `<option value="I must be quoted!!!">abc</option>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP post method only showing the first word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138467/php-post-method-only-showing-the-first-word)

Comment: thanks. numerous searches but was using the keywords for <select> so didn't show on my radar. been at this since yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this   `echo '<option value="'.$row['AllianceName'].'">'.$row['AllianceName'].'</option>';`

from this `echo '<option value='.$row['AllianceName'].'>'.$row['AllianceName'].'</option>';`